# Bootstrap 4 - 3 divs, 1 left, 2 right

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In Bootstrap 4, I have three divs:

```
<div class="row">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way, **without placing div B and C inside another div**, to achieve this:

```
A  B
   C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way, **without placing div B and C inside another div**, to achieve this:

```
A  B
   C
```

Yes, you can achieve this by using offset classes like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">A</div>
        <div class="col-6">B</div>
        <div class="col-6 offset-6">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Note: The column classes and the offset class are not responsive in the example shown above. To make them responsive, you need to add the appropriate infixes.

Reference:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#offsetting-columns

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#responsive-classes

> Now say div A is 600px heigh, B and C are both 50px heigh. I don't want A to push C down. I want C to go right below B. What now?

In this case, you'd want to use the `d-block clearfix` and `float-left` + `float-right` classes like so:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
<div class="container">
    <div class="row d-block clearfix">
        <div class="col-6 float-left bg-warning" style="height: 100px">A</div>
        <div class="col-6 float-right">B</div>
        <div class="col-6 float-right">C</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In this case, `d-block` switches from the default flexbox to "display:block" for the row and the `float-left`/`float-right` classes tell the columns where to float.

Reference:

http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/float/

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/clearfix/

Comment: Thanks. Now say div A is 600px heigh, B and C are both 50px heigh. I don't want A to push C down. I want C to go right below B. What now? :)

Comment: See the second snippet I just added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is assign a class to A and put a float-left in css, then its just a matter of margins etc.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="left">A</div>
   <div>B</div>
   <div>C</div>
</div>
```

Css code

```
.left{
float:left;
}
```

Comment: The `float-left` class exists in BS4

Comment: ohh, well then i guess he can use this than playing around with css